# Extension file doesn't show on JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

Declared extension files doesn't show on JFileChooser window. Here is my filter class:

```
import java.io.File;

public class AudioFilter extends javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter{
    public boolean accept(File f){
        if (f.isDirectory()){
            return true;
        }
        String extension = Utils.getExtension(f);
        if (extension != null){
            if (extension.equals(Utils.wav)
            || extension.equals(Utils.aif)
            || extension.equals(Utils.rmf)
            || extension.equals(Utils.au)
            || extension.equals(Utils.mid)){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String getDescription(){
        return "wav, aif, rmf, au, mid";
    }
}

class Utils{
    public final static String wav = "wav";
    public final static String aif = "aif";
    public final static String rmf = "rmf";
    public final static String au = "au";
    public final static String mid = "mid";
/*
* Get the extension of a file.
*/
    public static String getExtension(File f){
        String ext = null;
        String s = f.getName();
        int i = s.lastIndexOf('.');
        if (i > 0 && i < s.length() - 1){
            ext = s.substring(i+1).toLowerCase();
        }
        return ext;
    }
}
```

Here is my code to call the filter process:

```
AudioFilter audiofiler = new AudioFilter();
    boolean openFile() throws FileNotFoundException{
            JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
            jfc.setDialogTitle("Open File");
            jfc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
            jfc.setCurrentDirectory(new File ("."));
            jfc.setFileFilter(audiofilter);
            int result = jfc.showOpenDialog(this);
            if(result == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION){
                return true;
            }else if(result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                fFile = jfc.getSelectedFile();
                String file_string = readFile (fFile);
                if(fFile.isDirectory()){
                    String[] filesInDirectory = fFile.list();
                    for(int i=0;i<filesInDirectory.length;i++){
                        jList1.setModel(list);
                        list.addElement(filesInDirectory[i]);
                    }
                }

                if(file_string != null){
                    fTextArea.setText(file_string);
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Better to use [AudioSystem.getAudioFileTypes()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html#getAudioFileTypes%28%29) to establish which audio types are supported by the current JRE.  For example, my JRE (without any further sound types added via SPI)  reports it understands `WAVE`, `AU` & `AIFF`.  I'm not sure about `RMF`. WikiPedia claims Java Sound supports it, maybe it is not listed in the sampled sound formats because it can include MIDI data.  But in any case, if Java Sound suddenly supports `SND` or `MP3`, we'd want to include those in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested it too, it works fine. Post your full code, if you are still having problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tested your codes and modified a few for a simple test of file filtering (print out the selected file to std out) as follows and it works just fine for the `AudioFilter` object...

AudioFilter.java:

```
package file.test;

import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter;

public class AudioFilter extends FileFilter {

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File f) {
        if (f.isDirectory()){
            return true;
        }
        String extension = Utils.getExtension(f);
        if (extension != null){
            if (
                    (extension.equals(Utils.wav))
                ||  (extension.equals(Utils.aif))
                ||  (extension.equals(Utils.rmf))
                ||  (extension.equals(Utils.au))
                ||  (extension.equals(Utils.mid))
            ) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return "wav, aif, rmf, au, mid";
    }

    static class Utils{
        public final static String wav = "wav";
        public final static String aif = "aif";
        public final static String rmf = "rmf";
        public final static String au  = "au";
        public final static String mid = "mid";

        public static String getExtension(File f){

            String ext = null;
            String s = f.getName();
            int i = s.lastIndexOf('.');
            if (i > 0 && i < s.length() - 1){
                ext = s.substring(i+1).toLowerCase();
            }
            return ext;

        }
    }

}
```

AudioFilterTest.java:

```
package file.test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class AudioFilterTest {

    static AudioFilter audioFilter = new AudioFilter();

    public static boolean openFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
        JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();

        jfc.setDialogTitle("Open File");
        jfc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
        jfc.setCurrentDirectory(new File("."));
        jfc.setFileFilter(audioFilter);
        int result = jfc.showOpenDialog(null);

        if (result == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION){
            return true;
        }
        else if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            File fFile = jfc.getSelectedFile();
            String filestr = fFile.getAbsolutePath();

            System.out.println(filestr);
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            openFile();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

I guess you need to check your version of `openFile()` method...esp. your `readFile(File)` method

Comment: wow sir your a genious. this solved my problem: String filestr = fFile.getAbsolutePath(); many many thanks sir... :) :) :)